# android:: how to set app icon on app data directory in external storage ,

Tags: android, android-external-storage

I want to show my android Application data directory on external storage  like shown in image (with icon).
I am currently using simple directory to store files.

please give your thoughts on this . 
    thanks in advance ..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQbtH.png

Comment: This is a ES File Explorer function, you can't do this yourself.

Comment: yes that's right , but what i have to do in my app , so es file explorer (or any other file explorer )will recognise  my app data directory ?? .. like it does for facebook , whatsapp, etc...

Comment: Nothing. You can't do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

All folders on Android are normal folders, ES File Explorer not uses any recognition system, people associates folders and every association is sent to ES File Explorer's database and majority of associations wins and finally folder is assigned with icon.